# How can I bind to a programmatic property in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, binding

I have a form with a programmatic property called `SelectedAccessGroups`:

```
[Bindable(true)]
public string SelectedAccessGroups
{
    get { return "Selected Access Groups here"; }
}
```

I also have a `BindingSource` on the form which has a field called `EditableByAccessGroups`. I would like to bind my `SelectedAccessGroups` property to that field.

I attempted the following in my form's constructor, but it doesn't work:

```
this.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedAccessGroups",
  this.CriteriaBindingSource, "EditableByAccessGroups"));
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

**Update:** The error I was getting when attempting to run my program was quite undescriptive, but looking into it further, I found that I was getting the error because my property was read-only. I added a blank setter to the property, and the binding works fine now.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Does it show the initial value, and simply not show changes?

Comment: @Chris The error I was getting was quite undescriptive, but looking into it further, I found that I was getting the error because my property was read-only. I added a blank setter to it, and that works. Do you know of a way I could do one-way binding?

Comment: Looking at your edit, I think correct solution would be to set binding to OneWay, not creating empty setter. That is extremly confusing and any sane programmer would bash it over your head.
**Edit**: Damn, thats winforms. Not sure if it has one-way binding.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your class so the bound items will know when something is different.  here is an msdn article and there are several other articles out there that will help as well in implementing this interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Per your update and change of the question, to get one-way binding you could use use one of the other Binding constructors that takes DataSourceUpdateMode as a parameter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode.aspx

Comment: As I said on Chris's comment, I want the data source to be updated, but I do not want the binding to set my property. Is there a way to do a binding so that the data source does not attempt to set my property?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than add the cruft of a blank setter, try using [the overloaded constructor of Binding that takes a DataSourceUpdateMode value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158045%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and passing [DatasourceUpdateMode.Never](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode.aspx).  This will prevent the binding from attempting to update the datasource from the control.

Comment: That's not the problem, though. I want the DataSource to be updated with the property value, but I do not want the binding to attempt to set the property. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode.aspx) says that the DataSourceUpdateMode "specifies when a data source is updated when changes occur in the bound control."

Comment: If you expect the datasource to be updated, why would you make your setter blank?  I think you have the data source and the control confused.  The setting I mentioned prevents the control from updating the datasource via the binding, which is the 'right' way of doing what you are attempting with your blank setter.

Comment: @Chris I want the data source to be updated, but I do not want the binding to set my property. If I do a blank setter, nothing will happen when the data source attempts to set it.

Comment: Then the right way to do it is one way binding, not an blank setter.  That will prevent the binding from even trying to set the property, and you can remove your blank setter.

Comment: How can I do one-way binding which does not attempt to set the property but does set the field on the data source?

Comment: Use what I and Bueller suggested above.  That's what we are trying to tell you.

Comment: The setter of the property is what is triggered when something tries to set the property. It has nothing to do with updating the field on the data source. Using DataSourceUpdateMode.Never prevents the data source from being updated, not the property. Anyway, I got this whole issue resolved by not using binding at all.